# .on() not detecting dom change

Tags: dom, jquery

Having some problems getting my `.on()` working. My site is [here](http://www.eliteweb-creation.co.uk/dev/).

If you take a look at www.eliteweb-creation.co.uk/dev/js/nav.js, I am setting up some on `mouseenter` & `mouseleave` event handlers on `$('a.left.active')`

For the sake of anyone viewing this post in the future, I have added the code to jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TcbAP/

The anchors have `.active` added to them dynamically when clicked on, hence using `.on()` instead of `.click()` so that the jQuery detects the dom changes and adds the event handler.

My `.on("click")` for the anchors before adding the `.active` class are working fine, the issue seems to be for `.on()` not detecting the class change.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.on()` does not magically make your code detect changes.

You have to delegate the click event handler from an ancestor element that doesn't change:

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'a.active', function(e) {
    // Put your code here...        
});
```

You can read more about it in the [jQuery docs: **Direct and delegated events**](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: Great, this works perfectly! see updated example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/TcbAP/1/

Answer (score 0):

`.on` will only attach to elements that fit criteria *at the time it is run*, which is why they suggest putting such definitions in a `document.ready`.

From jQuery API:

*Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()*

It will not reevaluate your newly modified elements unless you run the `.on` definition again.  You can be more broad in your definition and check for additional classes if you want:

```
$('a.left').on("click", function(event){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    // Do fancy stuff here
  }
});
```

edit: code cleanup