# .click event not working after .load php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some html and jQuery code as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(e){
    $('.imgdiv').load('images3.php');
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});

<img id="preview">
<div class="imgdiv">
//PHP inserted images
<img id="image1" class="t" src="/images/image1.png">
</div>

$(".imgdiv img").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#preview").attr("src","images/image"+this.id.substr(5,6) + ".png");
});
```

However once the php has changed the images, this on click event no longer works. The  tags are exactly the same, as is the div structure they are contained with in. I have no idea what's causing this problem. Anyone?

Note that the prevent default doesn't work either - it jumps to the top of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you update elements inside the `.imgdiv` block, all events bound to the updated elements also *disappear*. To solve the problem, you may use [delegated events approach](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(".imgdiv").on("click", "img", function(e) {
   $("#preview").attr("src","images/image" + this.id.substring(5) + ".png");
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a change element, it may change the way click affect them, for support after doom element choose for

jQuery 1.8 or 1.7

```
$("body").on("click", ".imgdiv img", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#preview").attr("src","images/image"+this.id.substr(5,6) + ".png");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

jQuery < 1.7

```
$(".imgdiv img").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#preview").attr("src","images/image"+this.id.substr(5,6) + ".png");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Discussion about ".on" function after dom change: [.on() not detecting dom change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551696/on-not-detecting-dom-change?rq=1)

Hope this help