# dynamically added radio buttons change not detected jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a group of radio buttons being created while the page is loading, and I have attached a listener to them using `on()`, but the when I change the selected radio button, nothing happens.

Html:

```
<input type="radio" name="condition" id="cond_1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="condition" id="cond_2" value="2">
```

jquery:

```
$("input[name=condition]:radio").on("change",function(){...});
```

This has worked in the past, but for some reason, it doesn't appear to be working now.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '#cond1, #cond2', function() {...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [.on() not detecting dom change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551696/on-not-detecting-dom-change)

Answer (score 4):

Bind `on` to the body, or any closer ancestor element that doesn't change:

```
$("body").on("change", "input[name=condition]:radio", function(){...});
```

Comment: that worked, and now after I looked around a bit I realized that I was binding to other dynamic elements, mostly drop downs, but I wasn't binding the `on` to the `<option>` I was binding it to the `<select...>`